# Integer Array In C

Tags: c

I have the following code:-

```
while(string[i] != '\0') {
    switch(string[i]) {
        case '0' :
            numbers[counter] = 0;
            break;
        case '1' :              
            numbers[counter] = 1;
            break;
            case '2' :
            numbers[counter] = 2;
            break;
        case '3' :
            numbers[counter] = 3;
            break;
    } // end switch.
    i++;
    counter--;
} // end while.
```

For some reason either time any of the numbers[counter] = lines run the counter seems to get over-written with the number that I want to set the array to.

Comment: Please finish your sentence

Comment: and the question is??????

Comment: Sorry, finished the question now

Answer (score 3):

If I'm *guessing* correctly from the portion of code you posted without context, you probably want `i++` and `counter++`. Decrementing `i`, moving *to the start* of the string is especially unlikely to be right since you're expecting to find a `\0` at some point.

Comment: Yeah.  Especially since the terminating condition of the while loop is checking for a NULL char, it's incredibly unlikely he should be iterating backwards

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Haha, that's what I was just editing.

Comment: We don't know the context, we don't know what kind of problem he's dealing with. We don't even know what's being asked here... the only fact supporting your answer is condition `(string[i] != '\0')`

Comment: @LihO, that's a pretty convincing fact.  But yeah, the question is incomplete and should be closed.  But in all likelihood, cnicutar is correct.

Comment: All fixed, it was me being an idiot.